# Can't create MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I'm new in MySql triggers. I've got a task to create trigger that check inserted value but it throw an error in if statement and i don't know how to solve it

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF  new.price > @maxi 
        THEN
            ROLLBACK
        else
            INSERT INTO Laptop
            SELECT * FROM inserted
 at line 1
```

code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER ChekInsert BEFORE INSERT ON Laptop FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

        SELECT @maxi := MAX(price)*0.5 FROM Laptop
        IF  new.price > @maxi 
        THEN
            ROLLBACK
        else
            INSERT INTO Laptop
            SELECT * FROM inserted
        end if
    END
```

Comment: Always terminate your statements with `;`.

Comment: And a silent rollback in a trigger calls for confusion ("Why isn't the row inserted even though there is no error indicated?"). Better raise an error and don't use transaction control in triggers altogether.

Answer (score 0):

changed my code and everything is working

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER ChekInsert BEFORE INSERT ON Laptop FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare maxi float;
    select MAX(price)*0.5 into maxi FROM Laptop;
        if NEW.price > @maxi then
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'price is incorrect';
        end if;

end $$

delimiter;
```

To have multiple statements in the trigger you have to change the default delimiter and you doesn't need rollback because it's trigger when you throw an error